# mediaplayer.start() makes app crash only on Motorola Droid devices

Tags: java, android

I have a soundboard uploaded on the android market. The app is doing pretty well in the market(50,000+ downloads), but the developer console reports that I have an error, and this is bothering me.

All crash reports come from only one device - Motorola Droid. I've looked at what the error actually is, and it happens when I call the start() method for the MediaPlayer class. I get the following:

java.lang.NullPointerException:

at com.meeg.soundit.Soundboard.playAudio(Soundboard.java:2517)

the code for the method playAudio is as follows and line 2517 is mp.start():

```
public void playAudio(int resid){
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resid);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

Like I said, my soundboard has over 50,000 downloads, and it has 80 reports, all from the Motorola Droid. Is this something that I should ignore because 80 reports isn't much compared to how many people have used this, is there a problem with Moto Droid's and MediaPlayer, or is it just my code thats faulty?

Comment: a more detailed stack trace would be beneficial

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem earlier on some builds that causes playback from resources to not work quite right. But you should fix your code to check for null and display appropriate message to the user.